# How are "SourceX" and "SourceY" calculated when georeferencing an image?

Tags: arcgis-pro, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

When Georeferencing an image in ArcGIS, we create a table of control points. These points have 4 pieces of data: SourceX, SourceY, MapX, and MapY. SourceX and SourceY are the coordinates of the points within the source image.

The trouble is, the conversion between the pixel-coordinates within the image and SourceX and Y seems to be utterly arbitrary. the origin, where SourceX and SourceY are (0,0) seems to vary wildly between different TIFF images extracted from the same PDF Map source. While the conversion between pixel coordinate and SourceX and Y does seem to be linear, the actual conversion function is maddeningly inconsistent between different maps.

Currently, I'm experimentally figuring out the conversion by manually creating a few points, then running a linear regression to predict the "SourceX" and "SourceY" of the reference points in the image, but this is extremely labor-intensive, and I am sure there must be a better way.

**What is that better way?**

Comment: The better way is consistent extraction of pictures from same pdf. Not sure if this is possible

Comment: I still have the original PDFs, how would it be possible to get TIFFs from them that have a consistent pixel-to-position relation?

Comment: This is the issue and I don't think it's possible. So try to post new question, because title of this one is misleading.